# CSS determine first tag without text before it

Tags: css

```
<p><b>lorem ipsum</b></p> <- increase font size of b
<p>lorem ipsum <b>bold text</b></p> <- do not increase font size of b
```

Hello!

I'd like to increase the font-size of the first b tag in the p tag.
But in case there is some text before the b tag (second example) the font-size should not be changed.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: you cannot do this using CSS

Comment: ' But in case there is some text before the b tag (second example) the font-size should not be changed.' - can you make this clear? If there is text before the <b> the size of the font inside <b> shouldn't be changed?

Comment: in the p tag i have two scenarios: first: p with ONE b tag -> increase b font-size, second: p with N b tags -> no NOT increase b font-size

Comment: and in the case with N b tags, there is some text between the b tags without a tag

Comment: why you should use 'b' tag if you want the size to be changed in second example?

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments said it is not possible with pure css. You either need to wrap the other text in spans or use javascript.

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is target the `first-child` in css

like this:

```
p:first-child b {
 font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: `But in case there is some text before the b tag (second example) the font-size should not be changed.`

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
p b { font-size: 100px; }
```

it says select b inside p element. If you have more than one  inside, you can use :first-child like this:

```
p b:first-child { font-size: 100px; }
```

Comment: The question says: But in case there is some text before the b tag (second example) the font-size should not be changed.

Comment: I see. It looks like I didn't correctly understand the requirements.

Comment: yes it works, but it dos not meet the requirement :) simply said it does not do the job

Comment: my bad. As I said, I wrongly understand the requirements.